# Use S3 for HIVE metastore?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I'm configuring S3 to be a data warehouse for Hive. However, I'm not sure if the 'metastore' part of Hive can use S3 as a storage or not.

Most tutorials (i.e. https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-hive-metastore/) mention that the metastore only supports Derby and a few other RDBMS.

Is that true? Configuring metastore to use s3 as storage sounds like a simple config change to me.

Comment: Amazon S3 is not a relational database, nor is it a filesystem. Objects cannot be edited -- if an object is changed, it must be totally re-uploaded. Thus, it would not be a suitable candidate for a Hive metastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hive Metastore persists the metadata for Hive tables and partitions. It is backed by a relational database, and currently [MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, and MS SQL Server](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+Administration#AdminManualMetastoreAdministration-SupportedBackendDatabasesforMetastore) are supported. S3 is an [object store](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), not a relational database.

This is the [ER diagram](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12471108/HiveMetaStore.pdf) showing the various tables, columns and constraints stored in the Hive Metastore.